# Recent Mac laptop does not support VBOs

Tags: macos, opengl, glut, vbo

I have a mid-2011 Macbook Air with an Intel HD Graphics 3000 384 MB graphics card. Using OpenGL extension viewer, I am surprised to see 'GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object was not found, but is available in driver version 2.1 APPLE-1.6.30'. I would certainly expect VBOs to be available on such a new computer.

I am currently reading the OpenGL Superbible to learn modern OpenGL programming, however this aspect of it seems quite useless if even modern laptops do not support VBOs. Is there something I'm missing? Do other Mac users have this same issue?

If it has any relevance, I am using Mac OS 10.8.5 and am using GLUT initially to learn the basics.

Comment: Set your OpenGL profile to "Compatibility" when you run that program (and re-select the "Renderer" from the drop-down box) before examining the list of extensions. It will show up if you do this, but extensions are pretty much universally supported on OS X, since **Apple** implements the driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VBOs are part of OpenGL since version 1.5, so there is no need for an extension to be available. There is no requirement that the extension must be available if VBOs are supported in core.

This could also be an implementation bug, since not exposing this extension (as done before) would break a lot of software that relied on that extension.

Comment: I was not aware of this. As I am really new to OpenGL I was concerned when I was receiving an access violation for using VBOs. Must be a problem in the source code I'm using rather than the implementation of OpenGL....